How to solve WinSCP 5.19.2 vulnerability issue with BizTalk Server 2020 CU3
Currently we use BizTalk Server 2020 CU3 with WinSCP 5.19.2.
WinSCP 5.19.2 was found vulnerable by our security software Qualys and it recommends to update it to WinSCP 6.3.3.
Is WinSCP 6.3.3 compatible with BizTalk 2020 CU3 or we definitely need to upgrade BizTalk to CU5?
Is BizTalk CU5 really compatible with WinSCP 6.3.3?
We did not test the compatibility yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

With BizTalk 2020 CU 5 for KB5032872 - Improvement: Upgrade the WinSCP version used in the SFTP adapter to support updated SSH public key algorithms it says "6.1.2 or later versions"
So it should definitely work with 6.1.2, but you would have to try and see if it works with later version.
